# Calling multiple API's from another API in python along with user requests

Tags: python-3.x, api, flask

I am new to Flask API. I have build few API's for my project which I am calling through Postman and along with that I am passing user request in JSON format under the Postman Body.

For example:

```
@app.route('/data-cleaning', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def data_cleaning():
    if request.method=='GET':
       user_request = request.get_json()
       ....
       ....
       return X

@app.route('/data-transformation', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def data_transformation():
    if request.method=='GET':
       user_request = request.get_json()
       ....
       ....
       return X
```

Now I am running these two services separately in Postman and within each service I am taking  `user_request` by passing the JSON in Postman Body.

Now I want to create another API which should run both of these services along with user request. I tried to create the below script but its going in loop.

```
@app.route("/app2",methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def app2():
    # requests.get(url, params={})
    if request.method == 'GET':
        res = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/data-cleaning?table=outage_data", params= 
                                    {"column_name": {"punctuation": "yes","stopwords": "yes", 
                                     "lowercase":"yes","lemetization":"yes"}})
        return print('process completed')
```

In the above code i just tried to run one API from another API but in actual I need to run multiple API's.

Answer (score 0):

instead calling GET Request, You should be use direct use data_cleaning() and data_transformation() with passing parameters arguments, otherwise make third function and call it when needed.

```
@app.route('/data-cleaning', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def data_cleaning():
    if request.method=='GET':
       user_request = request.get_json()
       punctuation = user_request.get('punctuation')
       stopwords= user_request.get('stopwords')
       lowercase= user_request.get('lowercase')
       lemetization= user_request.get('lemetization')
       ....
       x = other_services({"column_name": 
                                    {"punctuation": punctuation,
                                    "stopwords": stopwords,  
                                     "lowercase":lowercase,
                                     "lemetization":lemetization}})
       ....
       return x

@app.route('/data-transformation', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def data_transformation():
    if request.method=='GET':
       user_request = request.get_json()
       punctuation = user_request.get('punctuation')
       stopwords= user_request.get('stopwords')
       lowercase= user_request.get('lowercase')
       lemetization= user_request.get('lemetization')
       ....
       x = other_services({"column_name": 
                                    {"punctuation": punctuation,
                                    "stopwords": stopwords,  
                                     "lowercase":lowercase,
                                     "lemetization":lemetization}})
       ....
       return x



def other_services(column_name=null):
    .....
    ---- some operation ---- 
    .....
    return x
```